# RESTful GET/POST Form Semantics

Tags: rest

When I GET from http://example.com/organization/ I get a list of organizations.

When I GET from http://example.com/organization/xyz/ I get the record for the organization xyz.

When I POST form data to http://example.com/organization/ I create a new organization.

What URL should I use to GET a form to fill out to create a new organization via a POST to http://example.com/organization/?

Looking at [How to do a RESTful request for an edit form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657454/how-to-do-a-restful-request-for-an-edit-form) and other sources, it would seem that I am really looking for a form resource for organizations -- so I should GET that form at something like http://example.com/organization/form/ and POST to http://example.com/organization/ as described above.  This seems...untidy though.

**Update**

tuespetre's comments have me thinking the best way to do this is to have a form resource.  The organziation form is provided via a GET to /form/organization/ which is filled out and posted to /organization/.

Answer (score 1):

A form in the sense that you speak of one is not a resource, but a template to gather user input to POST a new resource.

One really 'RESTful way' to do it would be to utilize some Javascript to 'include' that form in the collection page `/organizations`, either as a hidden 'slide-down' form or maybe a modal dialog that appears when a certain call to action button is pressed. This would make semantic sense for two reasons:

1. You won't have to have some arbitrary URI being used for the form (which is not really a resource in the sense that your domain objects are), and
2. the 'create' form is for POSTing to the collection, so it really closely relates to that collection and thus would not be at all out of place to have right there with the collection.

Of course, you will find many opinions on this, but I would rather not have arbitrary URIs that break the established pattern (i.e., you're not getting an organization with an id of 'new', so why have that inconsistency?)

Comment: Perhaps a better URI for the form to post a new organization to the list resource would be /form/organization/.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to implement it, I've seen it done in different ways and I don't think there's a rule (but there are different patterns/approachs that you could follow or not).
I would make it http://example.com/organization/new/